# Texture not showing in material preview

Tags: 3d-view

My texture is showing up bright pink in material preview. When I use render preview (cycles) it works fine.
After a lot of research I found out that the problem is that material preview uses Eevee and that the texture can not be displayed there. But the thing is I am following a tutorial and no one else seems to have this problem. And even in the video he is seeing his texture in material preview.
So I wonder if there is a way I can fix this problem? Any help would be deeply appreciated! [image]

[image]

Comment: Go to *File > External Data > Pack All Into . blend* then share your file on https://blend-exchange.com

Comment: my .blend file is too big, idk how to decrease the size

Comment: You don't need to show everything. just produce a simple setup that reproduces the problem. Just delete everything except one or more pink faces/areas then go to *File > Clean Up* and then share file.

Comment: Ok thanks! I added the file!

Answer (score 0):

When mixing together multiple normal/bump maps, EEVEE will turn bright pink, because it doesn't support this sort of rendering yet.

**You will need to view the material in cycles in order to see the mixed bump/normal mapped texture.**

*Note: if the texture remains pink in Cycles, it is most likely because one of the image textures in your file that you are using for your shading is missing.*

Comment: In my case it was because my GPU driver was outdated. After updating drivers, it worked.

Comment: Well, there you go! :D

Comment: Ok, but I read that the material preview is always using EEVEE? But if that is the case then how could others see it on material preview?
I am working on a Mac Mini with a 8-Core GPU, is it just not good enough for this kind of texturing?

Comment: You can't view non-EEVEE-compatible materials in *Material Preview.* You would need to go into *Rendered View.* (The fourth option after *Material Preview*) Also, that Mac is fine. Texturing doesn't really bog down computers. Rendering animations and stuff does! ;)

Comment: Ok thanks, I was almost worried that it could be my Mac! But still (I don't want to be annoying I just don't get it) if you look at this video: https://youtu.be/1aNnERnHRZg?t=715   he is seeing his texture in material preview. i did everything exactly as he did it, so why is he able to do that but I am not?

Comment: Well, you are working with fairly complex node setups, and when following a video it is pretty easy to plug in a wrong number and mess up the whole texture! So, maybe one of two things: 1. The guy in the video is using an older (or newer) version of Blender that you are using, and so there might be some rendering inconsistencies between the two. 2. You didn't make the *exact* same node setup he made, and so your material preview view is different. Do you mind sharing your .blend file on https://blend-exchange.com? Maybe I can find where your issue lies.

Comment: I put a "showcase" version of what i did in my original post. He is definitely using an older version, because the video is over a year old. I am almost certain I did everything like he did it, but I am new to blender in general and this is the first time I am using textures like this, so maybe I missed something :/ If you could take a look at it I would really appreciate that! ^^

Comment: I checked it out. Even in Cycles render preview it is pink, so this means your texture files are missing. Make sure that the images your textures are referencing are in the same places they were when you started the project!

Comment: then i did something wrong with the save file, 'cause for me it shows the texture in render view... I have to see how to fix it

Comment: if i pack the textures into the save file, then it's too big for blend-exchange... I seriously don't know what to do anymore...

Comment: Well, if it works for you, then it's solved.